# if I have a UITableView that filters results on a search, how do I set the IndexPath on ViewDidLoad() to be constant even when searched

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, search

I am trying to set up a `UITableView` that is searchable. Right now when the view loads there are 23 cells so the `indexPath` goes from 0 to 22, and if you click on the third cell it returns an `indexPath` of 2. But when I search something and click on the third result, it still returns a `indexPath` of 2. However, I want the `indexPath` of a search to be what it was originally loaded as.

Comment: Why do you need the same index path when searching? You can still access the data from the search array.

Comment: When I click on a certain cell I want to send the screen to another `secondViewController`. Prior to sending it though I set a struct variable `searchStruct.buttonTag = indexPath`. Then, at this `secondViewController` I call the `searchStruct.buttonTag` in order to determine what gets displayed on `secondViewController`. Is there another way to set the value of `searchStruct.buttonTag` equal to the orginal Index? @rmaddy

Comment: You definitely should not be setting a button tag of another view controller. Simply pass the data to the second view controller. Let that view controller update its own views.

Comment: Pass the array element, not the array index

Comment: I want to pass the array element, but I would do this in the `didSelectItem()` function of the `UITableView`. And I want to do this by doing: `passingData = theArray[indexPath.row]`; however, I can't do this without filtering `theArray` in the function provided above. Do you know how to filter this array when searching? @Paulw11

Comment: Why do you need to filter `theArray`?  You just need to get the element from `filteredCakes`

Comment: Just get element from filteredCakes and then You can just loop through theArray again and compare the elements, when both items are matched, the ith index will be the index of theArray.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to take a slightly different approach.

In your implementation of `func tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAt: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` you must be translating the `indexPath` into a one of your 23 data elements.  This would be true whether or not you are filtering by search criteria.

So, in your implementation of `func tableView(UITableView, didSelectRowAt: IndexPath)`, I would suggest that you do the exact same translation of `indexPath` in this function in order to get the correct data element.

Since you're implementing the same logic to use an `IndexPath` to get a data element, that logic should probably be in one function that both of the table view functions can share.

**Added Code Example**

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let cake = filteredCakes[indexPath.row]
        // bake your cell with your cake here
        // cell.textLabel.text = cake.description // or whatever

        return cell
    }
```

Then, when handling the user's tap:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cake = filteredCakes[indexPath.row]
        // do whatever actions you want now that the user has tapped
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it makes sense but I am still a little confused. Can you see the edited question and possible give me an example of what the code should look like? thanks, I really appreciate the help!